# Cannot import scipy.optimize due to absent dylib

Tags: python, numpy, gcc

Could you please help me? 2 weeks ago I did brew upgrade and that somehow broke some dependencies in my Python project (I think that was the cause as it was compiling before) and I cannot seem to import scipy any more. The error message I am struggling with is the following:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/albydeca/indProjSource/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack2.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/libgfortran.3.dylib 
Referenced from:/Users/albydeca/indProjSource/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack2.so
Reason: image not found
```

Triggered from :

```
File "/Users/albydeca/indProjSource/venv/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/scipy/optimize/linesearch.py", line 18, in <module>
from scipy.optimize import minpack2
```

This is due to the fact that my path is as follows:

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0/4.7.3
```

and fortran.3.dylib is not there

I have tried searching how I can get that folder but brew installing gcc49 does not do the job. My gcc choices are either 5 or x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Have you encountered this or similar messages before? Do you know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to avoid this problem.  Get a Python Distribution that has scipy included already.  It's called Anaconda from https://www.continuum.io/downloads 
To avoid this problem in the future is stop messing with your main environment by instead using virtualenv's or conda environments.